# selenium webdriver handle windows pop

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am saving image from to my local system with `selenium-webdriver` (using Robot class):-

1. First time it save perfectly.
2. When I run my script second time again then it tries to save same image with the same name but windows pop appear `The image with this name already exists. Do wish to save again` with `Ok` and `Cancel` button. How to handle this Ok button.

Comment: Another option is to just see if the file already exists. If it does, don't try to save it again.

Answer (score -2):

You can handle Windows pop-up using a 3rd party tool Auto-IT integrated with eclipse. This will consist of an script editor (where you have to write a piece of code and save as ".au3") and inspector (used to inspect the properties of the window pup-up buttons). 
**Refer to -** https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

Answer (score -2):

you could also try to just send an enter press which would press whichever button is marked by default

if its more of an overlay then a real popup (like jquery or jsf in java) then you can select the buttons using xpath

Answer (score -2):

Using selenium you can accept an Alert, try the following, I know this works in C#

```
IAlert alert = null;
try
{
    alert = BrowserProcess.SwitchTo().Alert();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    //no alerts present, everything is ok
}
if (alert != null)
{
    alert.Accept();
}
```

In java it would be something like this:

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alertText = alert.getText();
alert.accept();
```

Comment: OP asked for Java.

Comment: @Moe Ghafari:- Thanks for your help but i am asking for windows pop up, your code is for browser based popup.